# FastAPI ignores CORS middleware

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

I'm working on a back-end with FastAPI. When trying to implement CORS middleware it looks like if the app just ignores it. I'm using the code example at the FastAPI documentation with a specific origin domain so other API located on another server can make use of this. So I have my routers.py file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://xxxxxxx.appspot.com", #not the real domain
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Then I start my server using Gunicorn like this:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.routers:app
```

Now, if I try to call the API from my own laptop, which is not included as an allowed origin, like this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://x.x.x.x:8000' \. #server public IP
  -H 'accept: application/json' -v
```

It works and I get this response:

```
*   Trying x.x.x.x:8000...
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: x.x.x.x:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> accept: application/json
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Tue, 14 Sep 2021 10:36:41 GMT
< server: uvicorn
< content-length: 25
< content-type: application/json
<
* Connection #0 to host x.x.x.x left intact
{"message":"Hello World"}
```

The server is deployed at a Google Cloud virtual machine but when trying this on a VirtualBox Ubuntu machine it works the same way.

How should I actually define which origins are allowed?

Comment: CORS doesn't block origins, for instance, you will still be able to call the api with curl. CORS is enforced within the browser. I don't see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your pasted response, so I'm assuming it is working as intended.

Comment: in `curl` add this `-H 'Origin: http://xxxxxxx.appspot.com' and see what happens for different values.

Comment: Ok, thanks @John. Then in order to fully protect my API I should add another security layer like oAuth, right?

Comment: That is correct